# mySQL Selecting between two DATETIME

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, mysql-python

I am using python and mysql connector and am trying to get all eventids from the mySQL DB between two different datetime stamps.

The DB is

```
 eventid | date | homeodds | drawodds | awayodds
```

This is the code:

```
def findarbs(startdate, enddate):
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
cur = cnx.cursor()
command = "SELECT DISTINCT eventid, date FROM moneyline 
               WHERE 'date' > ('%s') AND 'date' < ('%s') 
               ORDER BY date asc" % (startdate, enddate)
print command
cur.execute(command)
result = cur.fetchone()
print result
while result is not None:
    print result[1]
    result = cur.fetchone()
```

And the call to the method:

```
findarbs("2015-03-01 15:00:38", "2015-03-08 15:00:38")
```

Now if I change the command to:

```
command = "SELECT DISTINCT eventid, date FROM moneyline 
               WHERE 'date' > ('%s') 
               ORDER BY date asc" % (startdate)
```

it sucessfully selects the correct eventids and dates. If I change it to less than it also works. But when I try to combine them or use the BETWEEN command I get NONE back.

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you certain there are actual records in the DB that fall between that date range?

Comment: Yes I'm sure there are. That was what I was hoping, would be an easy fix.

Comment: The issue was having date in ' ' I removed the ' ' and it now works. I really should rename date column.

Comment: @Vuzuggu yes you should :) while you at it remember that it's all too easy to do the same in python - id, dir - some of the big offenders...

Comment: Or just use standard conform SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong type of quotes:

```
'date'
```

-->

```
`date`
```

`'date'` is a string that evaluates as 0.

Also, not that neither :38 is captured by > and <.